# Relying on deterministic destruction, avoiding destruction on return

Tags: c++, c++14

I have been trying to rework my logging class. However, I'm facing a problem.
I want to expose this interface to users:

```
mylog() << "hello";
```

The idea is that `mylog` is an instance of `Logger`, which defines some useful characteristics for a defined log type. Its `operator()` function would return an instace of type `LogStream`. However, I would like to output the newline character automatically at the end, so I had the idea to do that in `LogStream`'s destructor.

My current implementation looks like this (`LogStream` and `Logger` being largely dumbed down):

```
#include <iostream>

struct LogStream
{
    ~LogStream() { std::cout << '\n'; }

    template<class T>
    LogStream& operator<<(const T& t)
    {
        std::cout << t;
        return *this;
    }
};

struct Logger
{
    LogStream operator()()
    {
        return LogStream{} << "message: ";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Logger log;
    log() << "hello!";
}
```

Interstingly, I figured out with this piece of code that my previous implementation depended on RVO. The compiler was always performing copy-elision, so the destructor did behave the way I want. However, with this piece of code, the newline character is being printed twice, because the copy constructor is being called when the copy occurs in `operator()`.
The problem disappears when I do not return the temporary instance, and instead put this in `operator()`'s body:

```
LogStream stream;
stream << "message: ";
return stream;
```

Now the RVO makes it work the way I want.
I later on `= delete`'d the copy constructors, because it made more sense anyway, which effectively causes the code to fail to compile.

What are my options to provide the interface I want, without using the hacky solution to rely on RVO?

Comment: Add a flag inside `LogStream` to indicates if you need to output a newline in the destructor, and set this flag to false when moving (on the moved object).

Comment: That would work and probably be the easiest solution, but I am not fan of it. I would rather keep the copy constructors deleted.

Comment: @Asu, if you can't use Holt's suggestion, you may need to compile with C++17 standard where RVO isn't a "may or may not" situation (in certain contexts like your code snippet),

Comment: The copy constructor is deleted, only the move constructor is not.

Comment: Right, this seems to work, though I would prefer a solution that doesn't use move constructors. Praetorian's solution looks pretty good to me :)
Edit: Also, I'm aware C++17 provides guaranteed elision in some cases, though I am sticking with C++14 for this project, at least for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a constructor to `LogStream` that takes a `char const *`.

```
LogStream(char const* c) { std::cout << c; }
```

Then, instead of creating a temporary `LogStream` within `operator()`, use list-initialization to initialize the return value itself.

```
LogStream operator()()
{
    return {"message: "};
}
```

The temporary is thus avoided along with the extra new line.

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d12db4d75db3495d) (note that even using `-fno-elide-constructors` to disable copy elision doesn't result in the extra newline).